# SimpleDateFormat Day of Week

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

At the moment I do it like this way:

```
DateFormat dateInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");  --> e.g.: Mo.
DateFormat dateInstance2 = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(); --> 09.11.2015

String s = dateInstance.format(date) + " " + dateInstance2.format(date);
```

But `DateFormat dateInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");` gets marked with the message I should use SimpleDateFormat.get....
But I need a output like this "Mon. 09.11.2015". without the notification from the compiler. thx for help

Comment: check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html try to use "EEE yyyy.MM.dd" format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need this?

```
DateFormat dateInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy.MM.dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
String s = dateInstance.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")` to your method or class. Ex:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public MonthAdapter(Context context, String monthFormat) {
    super(context, _months);

    _simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(monthFormat);
}
```